# greasemonkey to check tab page and add lines to table

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

i was trying to make a greasemonkey script that would create a table and add some lines on a new empty page/tab... The add lines and create table part is not hard but i am having some difficult on the part to create a new page/tab and use always that same tab to add more lines to the table each time i refresh the page. Is this possible ?

1. Refresh or open page
2. Create table and add info to the lines/rows on a new tab
3. Refresh or open page again
4. Add lines/rows to the existing tab

Thanks in advance

Comment: is the new page on the same domain as the webpage that refreshes?

Comment: it's probably the error on line 37

Comment: @dandavis - correctly written greasemonkey scripts don't have "same domain" issues

Comment: @JaromandaX: i believe for this use-case it does matter. the best way to pass the data/events is localStorage, and one site's localStorage can't set another's. The only other options i can think of are serviceWorkers (complex) and  popups, but that's weak sauce... Got a better idea?

Comment: @JaromandaX: i guess you could use a server+ajax/sockets to avoid the disappearing window ref issue, but i'd want a client-side solution if i were OP. a hidden iframe that caught url changes and pushed them to localStorage could work as well, but if it's on the same domain it's simpler. I'll post an answer once the OP clarifies the setup.

Comment: as the OP has not added any code to the question, I too could only speculate as to what the best course of action would be

Comment: Hi. The page where the information is on the internet and i guess the table page that will be created is a local one.The part to read the information is done and the place where the info goes to i thought i could do it using a excel google form and the post method to add it but could not understood very well how to make the google form and link both so thought that creating a temp page with a temp table would work and would not be complicated... offcourse if i close that table page all info is gone.

Comment: yes the internet page is on the same domain in this case...